# python-download all images from the webpages and into a file

Tags: python

I would like to download all images from this webpage, but my code are not workable.
How can I revise that given this script.

```
import requests,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html=requests.get('https://www.dreamstime.com/free-results.php?securitycheck=afbb79db0e7e374867295876228b135a&firstvalue=&lastsearchvalue=&srh_field=doges&searchby=doges&s_free=y&s_cc0=y',headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
html.encoding='utf-8'

sp=BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
images_dir="images/"
if not os.path.exists(images_dir):
    os.mkdir(images_dir)

all_links=sp.find_all(['a','img'])
for link in all_links:
    src=link.get("src")
    href=link.get("href")
    attrs=[src,href]
    for attr in attrs:
        if attr != None and ('.jpg' in attr or '.png' in attr):
            full_path=attr
            filename=full_path.split('/')[-1]
            print(full_path)
            
            try:
                image=urlopen(full_path)
                f=open(os.path.join(images_dir,filename),'wb')
                f.write(image.read())
                f.close()
            except:
                print("{} fail".format(filename))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl', headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
my_domain = "https://www.google.de"
# your problem is that the links are relative and do not have the domain name.
# You should check if http is present in the link,
# if not check if there  is a base element "<base href="https://example.com">"
# if there is add that to the URI, if not add the "my_domain"
# I cheated here and just added the my_domain directly, which will cause you issues if it is present.
html.encoding = 'utf-8'
sp = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
images_dir = "images/"

# print(f"My images path {os.path.exists(images_dir)}")

if not os.path.exists(images_dir):
    print(f"was not found {os.path(images_dir)}")
    os.mkdir(images_dir)

all_links = sp.find_all(['a', 'img'])

# print(all_links)

for link in all_links:
    src = link.get("src")
    # print(f"src= {src}")
    href = link.get("href")
    # print(f"href= {href}")
    attrs = [src, href]
    # print(f"attrs= {attrs}")
    for attr in attrs:
        if attr and ('.jpg' in attr or '.png' in attr):
            my_path = attr
            full_path = my_domain + my_path
            # print(full_path)
            filename = my_path.split('/')[-1]
            print(f"My image ref -> {my_path}")
            print(f"My full image ref -> {full_path}")
            print(f"My image filename-> {filename}")

            try:
                image = urlopen(full_path)
                f = open(os.path.join(images_dir, filename), 'wb')
                f.write(image.read())
                f.close()
            except NameError:
                print("{} fail".format(filename))
```

Comment: Can you explain how your solution works? While the code may answer the question, it would help learning this stuff if you explained what you did a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a new version, which works a bit better with site captchas. First I tried a useragent header, but sites ignore that offten.
If you want you can read out the cookie of a site first then add that too.
Here are samples that can be added as needed, with the data you collect when from the site.
# "cookie": "__gads=ID=b2281f3501a53....."
# "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win6....."

I must stress, this was an intellectual exercise, I would never take content I did not own, or am allowed to use only in a specific context. I see this code as a simple way to analyse issues with specific tags or take an inventory of which tags I am using for what.

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_domain_short = "www.google.de"
my_domain = f"https://{my_domain_short}"

# This tells the domain I am a human not a robot, to avoid Captcha's
html = requests.get(my_domain,
                    headers={
                        "Accept": "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,nl;q=0.6",
                        "Host": my_domain_short,
                        "Purpose": "prefetch",
                        "Referer": my_domain,
                    })

html.encoding = 'utf-8'
sp = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
tag_base = sp.base
print(tag_base)

# This is where I want to put my images locally on my machine.
images_dir = "images/"
print(f"My images path {os.path.exists(images_dir)}")

# if the images path does not exist make it.
if not os.path.exists(images_dir):
    print(f"was not found {os.path(images_dir)}")
    os.mkdir(images_dir)

# get all <a img=src tags>
all_links = sp.find_all(['a', 'img'])

# is there a Base href tag for the page suggesting relative URLs
base_path = sp.find('base href')
print(f"My base Path: {base_path}")


# print(all_links) # Print all found results, by removing comment "#"

# loop through results and get the pictures
for link in all_links:
    src = link.get("src")
    # print(f"src= {src}") # tests code
    href = link.get("href")
    # print(f"href= {href}") # tests code
    attrs = [src, href]
    # print(f"attrs= {attrs}") # tests code
    for attr in attrs:
        if attr and ('.jpg' in attr or '.png' in attr):
            my_path = attr
            print(f"My image ref -> {my_path}")
            # If the URI is Absolute, then ok URI is good, otherwise add the base path or my_path to it.
            if "http" in my_path:
                full_path = my_path
            else:
                full_path = my_domain + my_path
            print(full_path)
            filename = my_path.split('/')[-1]
            print(f"My full image ref -> {full_path}")
            print(f"My image filename-> {filename}")
            # Try and write the file to my local computer
            try:
                image = urlopen(full_path)
                f = open(os.path.join(images_dir, filename), 'wb')
                f.write(image.read())
                f.close()
            except NameError:
                print("{} fail".format(filename))
```

This is another simpler version which can be run as an import, or from the console or as a script, this one, in this case just lists the contents of a robots.txt as an example.

```
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen


def get_content(url):
    story = urlopen(url)
    story_words = []
    for line in story:
        line_words = line.decode("utf8").split()
        for word in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)
    story.close()
    return story_words  # if called through import words -> get_content() returns values


# how to stop function being used when importing, how to list imported functions
def print_content(story_words):
    """
    prints an input to the console, can be used in import
    """
    for word in story_words:
        print(word)


def main(url):
    """calls a function and calls a print function to print values
    Args: url: The URL of a UTF-8 text document.
    Returns: A list of strings from website.
    """
    # url = sys.argv[1] done in main instead for command line argument so that it is not run when importing
    words = get_content(url)  # calls fetch words, which returns values
    print_content(words)  # passes words to print function and prints returned values


if __name__ == '__main__':  # run as a script or if imported is ignored and
    # if called through import words -> get_content() returns values
    #  .\script.py https://www.google.com/robots.txt

    try:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    # this takes the input from console after command # I could have just called url and in main used url = sys.argv[1]
    # if the file is run directly then it just passes the url here.
    except IndexError:
        print("list index out of range")
        print('Module not run from command line passing ".\script.py https://www.google.com/robots.txt"')
        main("https://www.google.com/robots.txt")
```